# A potentially dangerous Request

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

I am new to asp.net. I am using "tinymce", there I am using html tables. On click of a button it's throwing an error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client 
(txtspecification="<table border="1" ce...").
```

Can anyone please help me in solving this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the `beginner` programming language? Never heard of.

Comment: please provide more details of your problem

Comment: Please check the answers before you vote to close a question.  This is a perfectly clear and valid asp.net question. Every asp.net developer worth his salt must have asked this question at some point in time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem will be that you are posting back to an ASP.NET page which has 'request validation' turned on. Essentially, the HTML from tinymce will contain angle brackets and that (amongst other things) will trip ASP.NET's security checking functionality (which is trying to trap cross-site scripting attacks). You can turn off request validation in the ASP.NET page.

Turning off request validation in page using page directive:

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

Comment: thank you for replying but i have added "<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>  
" but still its trowing same error

Comment: thank you for your reply..
i have added the code "<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>  
" but still i am getting the same error" any other solution pls...

Comment: Hmm. I suspect further user error. Maybe try turning off request validation entirely in web.config, by putting <pages validateRequest="false" />  in the <system.web> section. And be wary of cross-site scripting problems.

Comment: sorry for telling this.. i have used <pages validateRequest="false" /> in web.config file but still same error... pls give any solutions for this

Comment: Are you using classic ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC?